# strcmp segmentation fault

Tags: c++, c

Here is a problem from spoj. nothing related to algorithms, but just c

Sample Input

2

a aa bb cc def ghi

a a a a a bb bb bb bb c c

Sample Output

3

5

it counts the longest sequence of same words
http://www.spoj.pl/problems/WORDCNT/
The word is less than 20 characters
But when i run it, it's giving segmentation fault. I debugged it using eclipse. Here's where it crashes

```
if (strcmp(previous, current) == 0)
                currentLength++;
```

with the following message

No source available for "strcmp() at 0x2d0100" 
What's the problem?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--) {
        char line[20000], previous[21], current[21], *p;
        int currentLength = 1, maxLength = 1;
        if (cin.peek() == '\n') cin.get();
        cin.getline(line, 20000);

        p = strtok(line, " '\t''\r'");
            strcpy(previous, p);

        while (p != NULL) {
            p = strtok(NULL, " '\t''\r'");
            strcpy(current, p);

            if (strcmp(previous, current) == 0)
                currentLength++;
            else
                currentLength = 1;
            if (currentLength > maxLength)
                maxLength = currentLength;
        }
        cout << maxLength << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not a `C` question, tag removed

Comment: `'\t''\r'` <-- that's strange...

Comment: Very much a C question. Tag replaced. The use of namespace and streams is superficial to the code.

Comment: This isn't very C++ at all.  Personally i'd make `line` a string, use `std::getline(cin, line)` to read the line (eliminating the char array and the line length limit), wrap an istringstream around it, and use that to read each word (as a string, of course), eliminating the need for `strtok` and `strcpy`.  Since strings have an == operator defined, that gets rid of `strcmp`.  No pointers, no segfaults.

Comment: @cHao          i wanted to use a tokenizer within standard c/c++

Comment: @OrangeDog: Get the next token, as it's supposed to.

Comment: @ilthsafg: Choose one.  The preferred methods differ wildly between the two languages.

Comment: You don;t expect to see `\r` in the input that will usually be filtered from the input stream automatically. As Billy mentioned the extra `'` characters are probably mistakes.

Comment: @ cHao: As the user is tokenize the line why even get a line. Just use the >> operator to get a token at a time.

Comment: @Martin York    It's the way spoj expects the input

Comment: @Martin: Because the input can consist of more than one line, and if i'm reading it right, each line is counted individually.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is probably here:

```
    while (p != NULL) {
        p = strtok(NULL, " '\t''\r'");
        strcpy(current, p);
```

While p may not be NULL when the loop is entered.
It may be NULL when strcpy is used on it.

A more correct form of the loop would be:

```
    while ((p != NULL) && ((p = strtok(NULL, " \t\r")) != NULL))
    {
        strcpy(current, p);
```

Note. Tokenizing a stream in C++ is a lot easier.

```
std::string  token;
std::cin >> token;  // Reads 1 white space seoporated word
```

If you want to tokenize a line

```
// Step 1: read a single line in a safe way.
std::string line;
std::getline(std::cin, line);

// Turn that line into a stream.
std::stringstream  linestream(line);

// Get 1 word at a time from the stream.
std::string token;
while(linestream >> token)
{
    // Do STUFF
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Forgot to check for NULL on strtok, it will return NULL when done and you cannot use that NULL on strcpy, strcmp, etc.

Note that you do a strcpy right after the strtok, you should check for null before doing that using p as a source.

Answer (score 2):

The `strtok` man page says:

```
 Each call to strtok() returns a pointer to a null-terminated string containing the next 
token. This string does not include the delimiting character. If no more tokens are found, 
strtok() returns NULL.
```

And in your code,

```
while (p != NULL) {
            p = strtok(NULL, " '\t''\r'");
            strcpy(current, p);
```

you are not checking for NULL (for p) once the whole string has been parsed. After that you are trying to copy p (which is NULL now) in `current` and so getting the crash.

Answer (score 1):

You will find that one of `previous` or `current` does not point to a null-terminated string at that point, so strcmp doesn't know when to stop.

Use proper C++ strings and string functions instead, rather than mixing C and C++. The Boost libraries can provide a much safer tokeniser than `strtok`.

Comment: i used strcpy to initialize previous and current

Comment: @Roger Perkins  no. insert this statement cout << p before strcpy. it prints only one word

Answer (score 1):

You probably undersized current and previous. You should really use std::string for this kind of thing- that's what it's for.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing nothing to check your string lengths before copying them into buffers of size 21. I bet that you are somehow overwriting the end of the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using C strings, I'd suggest using strncmp instead of strcmp. That way, in case you are ending up with a non-null terminated string (which is what I suspect is the case), you can restrict your compare to the max length of the string (in this case 21).

Comment: Which won't help if you're trying to dereference the null pointer in the first place.

Comment: Agreed... but this would be a good additional check in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one...

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#define T(x) strtok(x, " \n\r\t")
char line[44444];
int main( )
{
        int t; scanf("%d\n", &t);
        while(t--)
    {
            fgets(line, 44444, stdin);
            int cnt = 1, len, maxcnt = 0, plen = -1;
            for(char *p = T(line); p != NULL; p = T(NULL))
        {
                len = strlen(p);
                if(len == plen) ++cnt;
                    else cnt = 1;

            if(cnt > maxcnt) 
                 maxcnt = cnt;
                    plen = len;
            }
        printf("%d\n", maxcnt);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```